# how to run web service on windows phone 8 emulator

Tags: web-services, windows-phone-8

I have created a web service and i called it in my Windows phone 8 application running on emulator but it throw exception. Refer the screen shots:
[image]

Here is the exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233087
  Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  Source=System.ServiceModel
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       Source=System.Windows
       InnerException: System.Net.WebException
            HResult=-2146233079
            Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
            Source=System.Windows
            InnerException:
```

Please help me

Comment: Here you go http://i.stack.imgur.com/bsPQQ.png

Comment: @Mayank Tripathi As Will said, Copy the exception detail to the clipboard, and edit your question and provide the details here.

Comment: i have modified the question and posted the exception